# How to set the default screen in react native bottom navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

This is my app with three navigation screen.

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Scan from '../containers/scan';
import List from '../containers/list';
import More from './more';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function Home(props) {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="List" 
          component={List}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Scan" 
          component={Scan} 
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="More" 
          component={More} 
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  );  
}

export default Home;
```

When I launch the app, "List" screen is visible.

How can I setup "Scan" screen as the default screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the initialRouteName prop of the navigator like below

```
<Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Scan">
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="List" 
          component={List}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Scan" 
          component={Scan} 
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="More" 
          component={More} 
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```